# No option to upload APK in play console

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, google-play-console

I cannot find an option to upload APK, only option available is to upload app bundle. I have a signed APK that I need to publish.

[image]

Comment: Stay up to date with the [Upcoming Android and Google Play Deadlines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Now we **can not upload `.apk`** files in the google play console anymore. Google has changed its policy from August 2021, to publish an app only with the **Android App Bundle(`.aab`)** format. Click [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html) for more details.

Comment: It should be able for pre-existing apps, right?
I'm trying to upload a new APK for an existing app (prior to 2021), but it doesn't allow me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since August 2021 You cannot upload `.apk` files to the play store you will need to upload an `.aab` file
For **Expo** you can generate the file as follows:

1. In expo app run `eas build --platform android`
2. Go to https://expo.dev and download the `.aab` file
3. In play store click **BROWSE FILES** and choose the `.aab` file from your computer to upload the archive.